# google activity api limit result userid not working

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

i try to limit the list activity to a specific user but i always get the same results. i've tried users email address and the user id from the user list api function, both are not working.

i found a an open issue here, without an answer: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=4974

my code:

```
        ActivitiesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Activities.List();
        listRequest.Source = "drive.google.com";
        listRequest.DriveAncestorId = "root";
        listRequest.UserId = "users email or Id";
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;

        IList<Activity> activities = listRequest.Execute().Activities;
```

additional info - i'm using a service account to authenticate

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to filter by user ID. Don't want to get into too many details, but the userId field has a different purpose that was never fully realized. Right now it's effectively ignored.